# Different types of Shards in Elastic Search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

In domain of AWS ElasticService, different types of shards and their count is mentioned as follow:-
[image]

What do different shards mean here? I wanted to create a index of my own in new Domain and their I wanted to give number of shards? I am thinking to use this API?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

What is the number of shards in API request object correspond to in picture?

Also, as I came to know we cannot increase number of shards later, so I wanted to ask is there any disadvantage if we give large number of shards. Eg. 40 shards for 20 nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess:

- You have 1 index with the default of 5 shards and 1 replica.
- You have a `.kibana` index (with the Kibana configurations) with the default of 1 shard and 1 replica.

  1. Replicas will only be allocation on different instances since it doesn't add any value in having multiple copies on the same node. If you only have 1 node, your replicas will not be allocated — those are your 6 unassigned shards.
  2. Initializing would be when you create new shards; relocating when existing ones are currently being moved around.
  3. If you create another index, your shards will be created according to your definition (or the default of 5 shards and 1 replica).
  4. Every shard has a specific overhead in terms of memory and file handles. Also the search results of each shard need to be combined. So having dozens of shards per node is fine, but avoid having hundreds or even thousands. And remember: Every index will add 10 shards by default (5 primary, 5 replica), so the number of indices will make your number of shards grow over time.